# Place UIView outside of UIViewController bounds

Tags: ios, uiview

Is there a way to add UIView outside of its container UIViewController?

Setting `clipsToBounds = false` to the View controller's View doesn't seem to help

Here I have View Controller A
I Add View controller B to View Controller A, with offset from top.
Then I'm trying to place Sub View outside of View Controller B (It should be placed partially on B and partially on A.
However, it gets cut and only gets draw on B

```
    -------- ViewController (A) ----
    -                              -
    -                              -
    -                              -
    - ------ ViewController (B) ----                         
    -                              -
    -       ------------           -
    -       - Sub View -           -
    -       ------------           -
    -                              -
    -                              -
    --------------------------------
```

If I place a UIView outside of another UIView bounds it works

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you have to set clipsToBounds = false also to the container view.

Comment: I set clipsToBounds = false to all the hierarchy and still it not working

Comment: Please update your question with the view controller hierarchy you have. Are you using a navigation controller or a tab bar controller?

Comment: @LorenzOliveto I updated the question

Comment: You have something strange going on, try to download this storyboard and see what are the difference with your (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vV-7nptaKCvXMoOD6IqspQlubdMzhaOo/view?usp=sharing)